# Storing Multiple Files for Each Instance of A Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a simple model of a `Student` and I'd like to be able to store an unknown amount of documents for each student. I thought about adding a `FileField` to the model but then I'd have to add a `FileField` for each document.

My question is what is the most efficient way to store documents for each student?

Edit:

I thought about using another model with a OneToMany field but then I got stuck because I also need to display all the associated files with a specific `Student` in his *admin change form*.

Comment: I think you may use another model for example document, then use a OneToMany field

Comment: @efirvida I thought about this option as well but I'd also like to display all the files that associated with a specific student in the admin change form. Is that possible?

Comment: yes it is posible by configuring the admin interface in the admin.py file, i´m not a django expert but i´m sure that its posible

Comment: maybe this help http://amir.rachum.com/blog/2013/06/15/a-case-for-a-onetomany-relationship-in-django/

Comment: Use the admin's `InlineModelAdmin` to show it on your admin UI, you can search how to make this inline a read only form and then you solve your problem. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mounir mentioned in the comments, I had to make another model (let's call it "`Document`") to contain the file with `FileField` and a `ForeignKey` to the `Student` model.

After that I had to assign that `Document` model to a `InlineModelAdmin` (I used `TabularInline`):

```
class DocumentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Document
```

And then just add it to the main `ModelAdmin` through `inlines`:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [
        DocumentInline,
    ]
```